# Duplicated data sent to EventMachine pubsub subscribers

Tags: ruby, websocket, redis, eventmachine

**Stack: Ruby 2.3.1, Rack, thin**

Simple websocket server:

```
require 'redis'
require 'em-hiredis'
require 'faye/websocket'
require 'json'

ws_channel = {}

App = lambda do |env|
$redis ||= EM::Hiredis.connect('redis://127.0.0.1:6379')

if Faye::WebSocket.websocket?(env)
ws = Faye::WebSocket.new(env, nil,
                         headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'},
                         ping: 15
)

ws.on :open do |event|
  puts 'client connected'
  query_string = event.current_target.env['REQUEST_PATH'].gsub(/[^a-z0-9\-_\/]/, '')
  ws_channel[query_string] ||= EM::Channel.new

  pubsub = $redis.pubsub

  puts "subscribing to ws channel: ws:#{query_string}"
  sid = ws_channel[query_string].subscribe do |msg|
    puts "WS -> ws:#{query_string}/ #{sid} #{ws_channel[query_string]}"
    ws.send msg
  end

  puts "subscribing to redis: #{query_string}"
  pubsub.subscribe(query_string) do |msg|
    puts "REDIS -> ws:#{query_string}/"
    $redis.setex(query_string, 60, msg)
    ws_channel[query_string].push msg
  end

  EventMachine.add_periodic_timer(5) do
    ws.send ({ :ts => Time.now.to_i}.to_json) if ws
  end

  ws.on :close do |event|
    puts "client ##{query_string} disconnected"
    pubsub.unsubscribe(query_string) if pubsub
    ws_channel[query_string].unsubscribe(sid) if ws_channel[query_string]
    ws = nil
    pubsub = nil
  end
end

ws.rack_response
end
end
```

**config.ru:**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'logger'
require File.expand_path('../app', __FILE__)
Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')

run App
```

**To start server:**

```
bundle exec thin -p 9292 -R config.ru start
```

**The issue conditions:**

1. Multiple connections established to the same WS channel from the same IP (multiple browser tabs have the same game opened on the same computer).
2. Single data push from WS server causes the data to arrive to EACH SUBSCRIBER as many times as there are subscribers.
3. If one of the tabs is refreshed (connection to WS server closes and reopens) subsequent data pushes do not cause the data duplication.
4. When a NEW connection is established, the scenario from #2 reoccurs.

My fix for this was to unsubscribe/resubscribe on connection open. so:

```
pubsub = $redis.pubsub
pubsub.unsubscribe(query_string) if pubsub
pubsub = $redis.pubsub
```

but this introduced another issue: when a tab is closed, the data stops arriving to the other tabs for about 30 sec. The WS connection is never closed i can see the 5sec pings in the JS console.

```
redis-cli $> PUBSUB NUMSUB <channel>
```

- this showing only one subscription to the channel, no matter how many subscribers are subscribed to the channel

**Target functionality:**

1. Multiple clients(subscribers) connect to the same channel from the same IP.
2. Each subscriber receives ONE copy of the data pushed by the WS server
3. Client disconnection/new client conneciton doesn't cause any service interruptions for other clients.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue, and I suspect the solution doesn't address the root cause... which means that the solution might break if you scale the application. Are you trying to limit each user to a single "game"? Is it okay for a player to have the "same game" open on different tabs? What about the the same player having the game open on different machines (or two different browsers)? Websocket connections are tab specific by nature (putting aide the availability of "shared-workers" on some browsers)... what is your objective.

Comment: Not trying to limit to one channel, but for the purposes of this example assume all users connect to the same channel. It's ok to connect to same channel in different tabs on the same or multiple browsers/machines. Objective is stated in "Target functionality"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Creating a unique EM channel per WS conneciton and unsubscribing a specific proc on ws.close and  seems to do the job:**

```
require 'redis'
require 'em-hiredis'
require 'faye/websocket'
require 'json'

App = lambda do |env|
$redis ||= EM::Hiredis.connect('redis://127.0.0.1:6379')
$pubsub ||= $redis.pubsub

if Faye::WebSocket.websocket?(env)
ws = Faye::WebSocket.new(env, nil,
                         headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'},
                         ping: 15
)

ws.on :open do |event|
  puts 'client connected'

  query_string = event.current_target.env['REQUEST_PATH'].gsub(/[^a-z0-9\-_\/]/, '')
  channel = EM::Channel.new

  puts "subscribing to ws channel: ws:#{query_string}"
  sid = channel.subscribe do |msg|
    puts "WS -> ws:#{query_string}/ #{sid} #{channel}"
    ws.send msg
  end

  puts "subscribing to redis: #{query_string}"
  subs = {}; r_callback = rand(Time.now.to_i)
  subs[r_callback] = Proc.new { |msg|
    puts "REDIS -> ws:#{query_string}/"
    $redis.setex(query_string, 60, msg)
    channel.push msg
  }
  $pubsub.subscribe(query_string, subs[r_callback])
  #puts $pubsub.inspect

  ws.on :close do |event|
    puts "client ##{query_string} disconnected"
    $pubsub.unsubscribe_proc(query_string, subs[r_callback]) if $pubsub
    puts "Unsubscribed proc: #{subs[r_callback]}"
    channel.unsubscribe(sid) if channel
    ws = nil
  end
end

ws.rack_response
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I think `em-hiredis` actually recycles the same connection and thread for Redis subscriptions... I'm not sure this is the case, but if so, than the following answer might be an overkill.

I would still recommend following the suggested design, as it would still save a lot of resources.

---

**Original**:

I'm not sure I understand the target functionality, but I do believe that there is a design issue reflected in the code. I also believe that resolving this issue will produce the correct behavior.

Although this is abstracted away by the `EM` layer, each Redis subscription client requires 1 new thread and 1 new TCP/IP connection (to the Redis server). It's possible things changed since I read the codebase for this, but somehow I doubt it...

... new (mostly sleeping) threads aren't as expensive as new processes (I think they cost a little over 1Mib per thread, mostly for stack allocation), TCP/IP connections are limited.

Even if this weren't an issue (and I assume that updated versions of the Redis connectors would resolve this), it's still somewhat resource wasteful to have the application read from a TCP/IP connection multiple(?) copies of data that the application already owns.

A better design would:

1. Create a global Redis channel for all events in an application. This global channel can be used to publish application wide broadcasts across processes.
2. Create a private Redis channel per application process. This channel can be used for direct communication between specific Websocket clients (using their host processes).
3. Assign each Websocket client a process unique ID (could be a simple numerator).

   Together with the process specific UUID channel, this local ID will allow a unique global identifier for each Websocket connection (the process UUID being a channel for the process that "owns" the connection).
4. Create a single thread (per application process) that listens to both channels (the global and the private channels) and "dispatches" messages to their final destination(s) within the process.

   The "dispatcher" should probably ignore any messages arriving from it's own process, to prevent double processing (this allows single process applications to avoid using Redis).

This design is the one I implemented in [the Plezi framework](http://www.plezi.io) and it's resource efficiency allows Plezi to serve a large number of clients concurrently.

Here's a quick example using Plezi, since I'm not very good with the Faye/EM API. Save this example as a `config.ru` file and run from the shell using the `iodine` (or `rackup`) command:

```
require 'plezi'
require 'redis'
# uncomment and update URL
# ENV['PL_REDIS_URL'] = "redis://my.host:6389/0"

class TimeAndEcho
  def index
    "return the client page using `:render` or as a simple string".freeze
  end
  def on_open
    # `id` is inherited from Plezi using a Controller module mixin
    puts "New connection with UUID (process+client): #{id}"
  end
  def on_message data
    # The data is sent to everyone EXCEPT self:
    broadcast :handle_message, data
    write "sent"
  end
  # broadcasting invokes a non-inherited method.. we will simply write the info
  def handle_message data
    # write is "inherited" using a module mixin when the class is used as a Websocket controller.
    write data
  end
end

Plezi.route '/', TimeAndEcho
# Idione's timer is in milliseconds.
Iodine.run_every(5000) do
  TimeAndEcho. broadcast(:handle_message, { :ts => Time.now.to_i}.to_json)
end
# Set the Rack application
run Plezi.app
```

In this example, the dispatching logic detailed above is implemented by the Plezi framework using a [`MessageDispatch` module](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi/blob/99bbc16ed4ea434bb75da71a04490c298c5f9192/lib/plezi/websockets/message_dispatch.rb#L44-L66) that sends and received messages using [Redis and a pub/sub thread](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi/blob/99bbc16ed4ea434bb75da71a04490c298c5f9192/lib/plezi/websockets/redis.rb#L10-L32).

Do notice that running this example requires a POSIX system (Linux / macOS / BSD) and the `iodine` server.

`iodine` implements the proposed [Websocket-Rack specification draft](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine/blob/d24544c741998910190d07410017124ed1a28dfa/SPEC-Websocket-Draft.md) and Plezi uses this native Websocket design for performance reasons.